# Eclipse Neon updates server with components I haven't saved

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide, sourcecontrol

Running Eclipse Neon 4.6.0 and Force.com IDE 37, and whenever I have it set to build automatically and work online, when saving changes to a component I'm finding multiple components updated that I haven't opened, edited or saved. I'm using source control to start from the latest code baseline regardless of the sandbox I'm working in, and I only want to push specific components to that sandbox. This is particularly a problem when sharing a sandbox with another developer, as it's overwriting their work!

I realise I'm not using the latest Eclipse or IDE version, but this has happened with earlier versions of Eclipse and force.com and I don't want to start changing things without some indication they'll solve the problem. I'd love to move to another IDE like Mavensmate or haoIDE but our corporate proxy requirements prevent them from working.

Are there any options to fix this besides just working offline and manually saving to server every time?